# Is this a type mismatch

Tags: applescript

I'm new to AppleScript and having trouble understanding something. Why doesn't the function valid_hex return true for these items? Clearly the data items are being obtained correctly from the tsv by reading paragraphs and text item 1 and 2 because the output string looks fine.

Is there a type mismatch that doesn't let valid_hex() do its job?

```
set inputStr to "8-1 Black\t232323\r\n8-2 Brown\tB5674D\r\n8-3 Orange\tFF7538\r\n8-4 Yellow\tFCE883\r\n8-5 Green\t1CAC78\r\n8-6 Blue\t1F75FE\r\n8-7 Violet (Purple)\t926EAE\r\n8-8 Red\tEE204D"

set accepted to {}
set rejected to {}
set acceptedCount to 0
set rejectedCount to 0

set atids to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tab

repeat with p in (paragraphs of inputStr)
    set aLine to text of (p as string)

    repeat 1 times
        set colorName to text item 1 of aLine
        set hexColor to text item 2 of aLine

        log hexColor & " named " & colorName & " is valid: " & valid_hex(hexColor)

    end repeat

end repeat

on valid_hex(s)
    set validhex to {"#", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}
    if not (length of s = 6 or (length of s = 7 and s begins with "#")) then return false

    repeat with c in (text items of s)
        if validhex contains c then
            set status to true
        else
            set status to false
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    return status
end valid_hex
```

UPDATE: Based on the accepted answer the original problem has been resolved. This is the full script. It takes a delimited list of hex colors with names and creates an Xcode .colorset folder for each one that can be dragged directly into an Xcode Assets catalog to be used as a named color.

It works pretty well, but if an error file is created, it doesn't go into the same `working_folder`.

```
use AppleScript version "2.5"
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

try
    set src to (choose file with prompt "choose input file")
    set o to (open for access src)
    set inputStr to (read o)
    close access o
end try

tell application "Finder"
    set working_path to container of (src) as string
end tell

set accepted to {}
set rejected to {}
set acceptedCount to 0
set rejectedCount to 0

repeat with aLine in (get paragraphs of inputStr)
    set old_delimits to AppleScript's text item delimiters -- Save the original delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tab
    set {colorName, hexColor} to text items of aLine
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to old_delimits -- Restore the original delimiters

    repeat 1 times
        if not valid_hex_color(hexColor) then
            set rejectedCount to rejectedCount + 1
            copy "Rejected " & "\"" & colorName & "\"" & " with hex value: " & hexColor & "\n" to the end of rejected
            exit repeat
        else
            set acceptedCount to acceptedCount + 1
            set redComponent to text 1 thru 2 of hexColor
            set greenComponent to text 3 thru 4 of hexColor
            set blueComponent to text 5 thru 6 of hexColor
            set jsonString to "{\n\t\"info\": {\n\t\t\"version\": 1,\n\t\t\"author\": \"xcode\"\n\t},\n\t\"colors\": [\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t\"idiom\": \"universal\",\n\t\t\t\"color\": {\n\t\t\t\t\"color-space\": \"srgb\",\n\t\t\t\t\"components\": {\n\t\t\t\t\t\"red\": \"0x" & redComponent & "\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"green\": \"0x" & greenComponent & "\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"blue\": \"0x" & blueComponent & "\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\"alpha\": \"1.000\"\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}\n\t]\n}"


            tell application "Finder"

                set folderName to colorName & ".colorset"
                set fldr to (make new folder at working_path with properties {name:folderName})

            end tell

            set resultFilePath to (working_path as string) & folderName & ":Contents.json"
            set outFile to (open for access resultFilePath with write permission)
            write jsonString to outFile starting at 0
            close access outFile


            copy colorName & "\n" to the end of accepted

        end if
    end repeat
end repeat

if rejectedCount > 0 then
    set summary to "\nrejected " & rejectedCount & ":\n--------------------\n" & rejected & "\naccepted " & acceptedCount & ":\n--------------------\n" & accepted

    set errorFilePath to (working_path as string) & ":RejectedItems.txt"

    log working_path & errorFilePath

    set errorFile to (open for access errorFilePath with write permission)
    write summary to errorFile starting at 0
    close access errorFile

    display dialog ("Rejected " & rejectedCount & " items, see " & errorFilePath & ".")
end if

on valid_hex_color(s)
    set validhex to "0123456789ABCDEF"
    if s begins with "#" then set s to text 2 thru -1 of s
    if the length of s ≠ 6 then return false

    repeat with c in characters of s
        if validhex does not contain c then return false
    end repeat

    true
end valid_hex_color
```

Comment: ➀ `repeat 1 times` is unnecessary and ought to be removed. ➁ `set aLine to text of (p as string)` is the wrong use of `text of…` and `p` doesn't need coercing to `string`. You can safely remove that line, then use `repeat with aLine in paragraphs of inputStr` instead. ➂ `"#AABC#2"` should fail hex validation, but it will pass (provided you've implemented Vadian's correction). ➃ Modified version of your script available for review here: [https://paste.ee/p/dpiMz](https://paste.ee/p/dpiMz).

Comment: Well, the thing is, my question is a minimized version of my overall code to highlight the parts I was having trouble with. I'm pretty sure I need 'repeat 1 times' but I'm not 100% sure. I thought about adding my complete updated code to the question for reference but I don't want to waste anyone's time with my beginner mistakes. I guess I could post it as an answer for reference, I just don't want this to turn into another question that gets downvoted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
repeat with c in (text items of s)
```

At this moment `text item delimiters` is set to `tab` so there is only one text item which is always the entire string.

To get each character replace it with

```
repeat with c in (get characters of s)
```

The `get` keyword is important to retrieve the list only once.

The first repeat loop is a bit cumbersome, this is sufficient

```
repeat with aLine in (get paragraphs of inputStr)
    set {colorName, hexColor} to text items of aLine
    log hexColor & " named " & colorName & " is valid: " & valid_hex(hexColor)
end repeat
```

And don't forget to reset `text item delimiters`

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to atids
```

---

A more sophisticated way to check the string is with AppleScriptObjC and Regular Expression (put the `use` lines at the beginning of the script)

```
use AppleScript version "2.5"
use framework "Foundation"

on valid_hex(s)
    set regex to current application's NSRegularExpression's regularExpressionWithPattern:"^#?[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}$" options:0 |error|:(missing value)
    return (regex's numberOfMatchesInString:s options:0 range:{location:0, |length|:(count s)}) as integer is 1
end valid_hex
```

Comment: This works, thanks for the additional suggestions. I made my question as basic as possible with what I was having problems with, but when I try to incorporate this into my full project, I'm having another problem. The main source of my data is a txt file in normal usage. But when I add `use AppleScript version "2.5"` & `use framework "Foundation"`, then when I try `set src to (choose file with prompt "choose input file")` I get a syntax error `Expected “,” but found class name.` with "file" highlighted. Otherwise, if I just use the `valid_hex` in its original form, everything works well.

Comment: You have to add also the line `use scripting additions` because `choose file` belongs to those.

Comment: ➀ _"The get keyword is important to retrieve the list only once."_ Is this something you've confirmed to be true recently, or is this something that was true in earlier versions of AppleScript ?  ➁ _"never forget to reset text item delimiters"_ This isn't necessary. The issue to which this pertains only arises inside applications that create a single AppleScript instance in which to run multiple scripts. I'm not aware of many that do this. Regardless, a better piece of advice is to always set them **before** splitting with `text items` or coercing a `list` to `text`. Then forget about them.

Comment: @CJK Both suggestions are more good practices than necessities. Regarding ➀: With the `get` keyword the list is evaluated only once. This is much more efficient especially if there is a `whose` clause e.g. `for a in b whose c is 0` or if the list is modified while being enumerated. This affects all versions of AppleScript.

Comment: Without the `get` keyword, the list is also evaluated only once. And since `get` dereferences list objects, it's actually much **less** efficient.  In the special case of a `whose` filter used _directly in the declaration_ of a `repeat` loop, then `get` **is** necessary, but not for the reasons you state: it's needed in order to dereference the `whose` filter _before_ it is enumerated otherwise a reference to `item n` would compound with a reference to a collection and then _that_ whole thing would be evaluated, at best incorrectly, but more likely unsuccessfully due to a bad reference.

Comment: With regards to resetting text item delimiters, I would also argue that **"never"** in bold is much more than just a suggestion for good practice, but also that—while it once _was_ good practice—it's now pretty bad practice to keep passing this mantra on when it has very little relevance to modern day AppleScript, and when there's an even better good practice-recommendation as already described, which reduces the number of lines of code, improves readability, eliminates the need for an additional variable, and negates worry if multiple scripts share a single AppleScript instance (this is rare)